# i18n with webpy

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext, web.py

i Have a problem with i18n, using webpy.

I have followed this : http://webpy.org/cookbook/i18n_support_in_template_file

So, in my .wsgi there is :

```
#i18n
gettext.install('messages',I18N_PATH,unicode=True)
gettext.translation('messages',I18N_PATH,languages=['fr_FR','en_US']).install(True)
```

So i ran :

```
pygettext.py -a -v -d messages -o i18n/messages.po controllers/*.py views/*.html
```

I have copied and translated messages.po, I have also change the "content-type" and the "content-transfer-encoding:

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8\n"
```

And i ran this command:

```
msgfmt -v -o i18n/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo i18n/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
>>>93 messages traduits.
```

here is the arborescence of i18n folder:

```
i18n/:
en_US  fr_FR  messages.po

i18n/en_US:
LC_MESSAGES

i18n/en_US/LC_MESSAGES:
messages.mo  messages.po

i18n/fr_FR:
LC_MESSAGES

i18n/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES:
messages.mo  messages.po
```

But when i go in my website (my browser's language is "fr_fr"), i haven't the string translated.

And I don't know why.
Anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

web.py documentation explains it in here.

http://webpy.org/cookbook/runtime-language-switch